# Javascript Uncaught TypeError after creating local copy of Turf.js with Browserify

Tags: javascript, browserify, turfjs

I have some Javascript code that uses Turf.js to manage some geospatial calculations. These were working by importing the full Turf.js file in script tags:

```
<script src='https://unpkg.com/@turf/turf/turf.min.js'></script>
```

but it's quite large size so I followed the [steps](https://turfjs.org/getting-started) to create a local copy with only the functions my code requires.

I created a `main.js` with the functions I need:

```
module.exports = {
    center: require('@turf/center'),
    distance: require('@turf/distance'),
    helpers: require('@turf/helpers'),
    lineIntersect: require('@turf/line-intersect')
};
```

and ran browserify command to create the local Javascript file:

```
browserify main.js -s turf > javascript/external/outTurf.js
```

then removed the original turf import and added my new local script to the head instead:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/external/outTurf.js"></script>
```

however when I try to complete functionality that uses Turf functions I get the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: turf.point is not a function
```

which I guess means it can't find it? So I looked in the browser debugger to see if the file is included, which it is and I can even find the referenced function there too:

```
function point(coordinates, properties, options) {
    if (options === void 0) { options = {}; }
    var geom = {
        type: "Point",
        coordinates: coordinates,
    };
    return feature(geom, properties, options);
}
exports.point = point;
```

EDIT:
I managed to get it working, but the solution has made the code more difficult to read.

For the distance, center and lineIntersect functions that only contain one function, I've had to add a call to default like below:

before:

```
`turf.lineIntersect(param1, param2);`
```

after:

```
`turf.lineIntersect.default(param1, param2);`
```

It works, but I don't understand why I need to specifically call default as the help page makes no mention of having to do that and it worked before I replaced the turf.js import.

The helpers import however requires a call to the helper and then helper function like so:

before:

```
turf.multiPolygon(featureDetails);
turf.polygon(featureDetails);
```

after:

```
turf.helpers.multiPolygon(featureDetails);
turf.helpers.polygon(featureDetails);
```

This isn't as bad as it doesn't require an explicit call to the default method, but again I'm not sure why I've had to do this.

Comment: maybe use `import` instead of `require`??

Comment: I have the same issue...